# Insert value into mysql via python says 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, mysql

Trying to get temperature value into mysql via python:

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import glob
import MySQLdb
from time import strftime

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
temp_sensor = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000000000cff/w1_slave'

# Variables for MySQL
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user",passwd="", db="db")
### cur = db.cursor()
mycursor = mydb.cursor() 

def tempRead():
    t = open(temp_sensor, 'r')
    lines = t.readlines()
    t.close()

    temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
    if temp_output != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string)/1000.0
    return round(temp_c,1)

while True:
    temp = tempRead()
    print temp
    datetimeWrite = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d ") + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    print datetimeWrite
    sql = ("INSERT INTO readings (cffr) VALUES (%s);" (temp),)
    mycursor.execute(sql)

    mydb.commit()



print(cur.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Run the above, I get:

```
8.4
2020-03-02 14:03:25
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dallas123.py", line 33, in <module>
    sql = ("INSERT INTO readings (cffr) VALUES (%s);" (temp),)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I've tried several changes to brackets and commas, but I've gone code blind and can't see wood for trees. What's the fix for this please?

Comment: `sql = ("INSERT INTO readings (cffr) VALUES (%s);" (temp),)` should be `sql = ("INSERT INTO readings (cffr) VALUES (%s);" % temp)`

Answer (score 1):

```
("INSERT INTO readings (cffr) VALUES (%s);" (temp),)
```

There's just a space between the query and the `(temp)`. And there's a comma *after* the `(temp)`.

You may have intended to write `%` there, but frankly that's not really correct either as it's an SQL injection vector. Instead you should give the `execute` method separate "query" and "arguments" parameters so it can take care of proper escaping:

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO readings (cffr) VALUES (%s)", [temp])
```

Answer (score 0):

`mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO readings (cffr) VALUES (%s)", [temp])`
That works fine, thank you.